# Bazel rules_k8s - How to Apply External Configuration Files? (From URL)

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, bazel, kubectl

I am trying to fully automate the deployment to my Kubernetes Cluster with Bazel and [rules_k8s](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_k8s).
But I don't know how to apply external configurations to my cluster.
Usually I would run a command like

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v0.12.0/cert-manager.yaml
```

But I want this to happen automatically when I run my

```
k8s_objects(
    name = "kubernetes_deployment",
    objects = [
        "//kubernetes:nginx",
        "//services/gateway:k8s",
        "//services/ideas:k8s",
        # ...
    ]
)
```

rule to deploy everything to Kubernetes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in your BUILD file, I'm not sure its the best way as it will be re-ran on every build. It would be nice if we could use an  [http_file](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/repo/http.html#http_file) here instead of a genrule.

```
genrule(
        name = "extyaml",
        srcs = [],
        outs = ["certman-k8s.yaml"],
        cmd = "curl -L https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v0.12.0/cert-manager.yaml > $@",
    )


    k8s_object(
        name = "certman",
        cluster = "minikube",
        template = ":certman-k8s.yaml",
    )
```